# Can i change a picture with ''<div class='home-icon''html to a picture in a link?

Tags: css, class, html, blogger

I want to edit this picture.
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-42H3onuga5o/UYs7FXqbSlI/AAAAAAAABHU/Pv2iKLwVl4s/s1600/aboutus.png
I see in the edit blogtemplate html editor:

```
<li>
                    <div class='menu-abs-bg background-color'/>
                    <div class='menu-specs'>
                        <div class='home-icon'/>
                        <a href='http://rivadotaku.blogspot.com/' title='Home'>Home</a>
                        <span>Rivadotaku&#39;s Blog</span>
                    </div><ul/></li>
                <li>
```

How to change the picture? You can see in the www.rivadotaku.blogspot.com, in the right bar.
I just a newbie, i only can edit a picture in this html

```
<img alt='' src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-S0aK8YBRU20/UYzIzLBILSI/AAAAAAAABIY/np2T4NYR9ng/s320/article1.png'/>
                <a href='http://www.templateism.com' style='background-color: rgba(108,203,103,.9);'>templateism.com
```

Please help me, sorry for bad English.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are tryng to do. If you just want to show another picture instead of the picture you are showing right now, you have to change the `src` attribute.

```
<img alt='' src='http://newlink.com/newimg.png' />
```